# auto generate download link with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-click

i generate my download link from this script

https://github.com/joshpangell/single-use

for example: 
download url generated like this:

http://cloud.joshpangell.com/singleuse/download.php?key=key580e36b2ce7ff2.31652971&i=0

everytime i generate the key by cronjob saved the key on text.txt like this:

```
key580e36b2ce7ff2.31652971
```

so my question How to include this key generated in the button download.

i`m newbie please explain with example.

here is example of my request:

```
<html ng-app="dApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Download file</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var dApp = angular.module('dApp', []);
      dApp.controller('dCtrl', function ($scope){
        $scope.dLink = 'text.txt';
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="dCtrl">
<a class= 'btn btn-primary' href="'/su/pathproduct/download.php?{dLink}' + '&i=0'">Download</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<html ng-app="dApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Download file</title>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var dApp = angular.module('dApp', []);
    dApp.controller('dCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
      // get a key from the text.txt file
      $http.get('text.txt').then(function (response) {
        $scope.dLink = response.data;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="dCtrl">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" 
     ng-if="dLink" 
     ng-href="/su/pathproduct/download.php?key={{ dLink }}&i=0'">Download</a>

</body>
</html>
```

1. added `$http` request which fetches a key from the text file and then sets it to or scope variable
2. added `ng-if` to the link, so the link is not visible while dLink is empty

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed three possible mistakes in the anchor tag.

1. Use ng-href instead of href
2. Instead of using {{dLink}} after download.php? you've used {dLink}
3. Remove the single quotes and plus sign from the href

Extract the key from text.txt and store it in the $scope.dLink variable

Remember to use ng-href and two {{}} when calling a variable in an anchor tag href attribute

Update:

```
$scope.dLink = 'key580e36b2ce7ff2.31652971';

<a class= 'btn btn-primary' ng-href="/su/pathproduct/download.php?key={{dLink}}&i=0">Download</a>
```

More on the ng-href have a look at [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) docs

Comment: hi @Chief the key will change every couple hours, so i can`t add or extract the key by manual, the first solution from @Andriy is what i need, thank you for your trying :)